# Android data model with only the fields that I need

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

If I make use of Retrofit and a data model. Does the data model need to have all the fields that the API returns? I only need some fields.

Comment: No, you can have only the ones you want, other fields will be ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't have to write all the fields that the API is returning. You can only write the fields that you want, and leave the rest of them as is.

Also, as a side note, don't forget to add annotations to your model variables using `@SerializedName("key")` to allow `Serialization` and `deserialising` of objects, just something to keep in mind while working with API's.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not requirement. If you need only one field just declare one field and only this field will obtain its value. However, you should note that, declaring only some field does not mean you only receive value of these fields. You will get receive all field but Gson converter produces compact java object for you

Answer (score 1):

It is not required, if the values are not needed, just don't add them. However, if they come or not in the response you can use nullable operator (?) of kotlin, so you can handle whereas it come or not.
In this example, if phone is present in the response it is parsed. And if it's not present it is not parsed. If you do not use (?) operator and phone is not present it throws and exception.

```
data class AdMessage(@SerializedName("body") val message: String,
                          @SerializedName("email") val email: String,
                          @SerializedName("name") val name: String,
                          @SerializedName("phone") val phone: String?)
```